# Parsing Conditional Expressions to String

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expressionvisitor

I'm looking for a way of parsing a conditional expression to a string.

The best example I can think of is LINQ-to-SQL. It uses ExpressionVisitors to format "Where" clauses. Example:

```
from a in b where a.x == 5 && a.y < 3 select a
```

That would translate into the following string (approximately, MSSQL is not current for me):

```
"SELECT * FROM b WHERE x = 5 AND y < 3"
```

From what I've read, this was done using the ExpressionVisitor class, as explained in this article: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii)

Now the problem is that I don't use LINQ, but I need this particular functionality. Is there a way of parsing a condition like that? I'm willing to do anything with reflection, delegates, lambda, etc.

Honestly, I don't think it's possible, but my *brain is a bit fried* (read: be nice if the question is ridiculous), so I figured I might just as well give S/O a try.

**EDIT**: Final usage example:

```
// Usage:
foo.Bar(foo => foo.X == 5 && foo.Y < 3)

// Ideal string output (variable name (foo) is not needed):
"foo.X == 5 && foo.Y < 3"
```

**EDIT 2**: Yes, a number can be lower than 3 and equal to 5. Told you my brain is fried.

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL does exactly this. If you write your own, you’d be reimplementing LINQ-to-SQL, which already exists — that seems like a pointless effort. (Yet people have done it; google for IQToolkit for example.) You said “I don't use LINQ” but your code says the opposite (it’s full of LINQ; expression trees are considered to be part of LINQ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is about about building the expression tree itself, then you could leverage C# compiler abilities.

It is legal to pass a lambda expression to a function acception an Expression>, as long as type arguments of Func are known. For example

```
 private static void PrintExpression(Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(lambda.ToString());
 }
```

can be called as

```
 PrintExpression(a=> a > 0 && a < 5);
```

You can improvise with generics as

```
private static void PrintExpression<T1,T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> lambda)
{
      Console.WriteLine(lambda.ToString());
}
```

and calling it with

```
   PrintExpression<int, bool>(a=> a > 0 && a < 5);
```

For custom printing of the expression part, you can write a simple recursive function that prints an expression or any other logic that suits you.

Remember, the lambda expression is compiled into an Expression at compile time - so can't subsititute it with already compiled Func.

As an alternative to this, you can always build a custom query provider, but that would be slightly deviating from the purpose - as you'd need to bind it some sort of queryable (custom again).

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
static string GetExpressionString<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return expression.Body.ToString();
}
```

Usage as so:

```
string s = GetExpressionString<Foo>(foo => foo.X == 5 && foo.Y < 3);
```

Which will return:

```
((foo.X = 5) && (foo.Y < 3))
```

Comment: Oh wow, I swear mho's answer wasn't here when I posted mine! His is a bit more in-depth, but I'll leave mine here I guess.

Comment: I'd like to add that removing any strong typing and allowing "object" would be much more useful. :)